# Scratch Org users can't login from https://test.salesforce.com

Tags: authentication, salesforce

After creating new users and waiting a few minutes for the user information to be synchronised between scratch org and test.salesforce.com, they cannot log in from https://test.salesforce.com.
The sysadmin user can log in from test.salesforce.com as well as from the scratch org domain.
My Domain -> Routing an Policies -> Prevent login from https://test.salesforce.com option is disabled

When I try to connect to one of the users, I get in the browser console:
GET https://c.salesforce.com/wbin/www-core/f/g 403 (Forbidden).

Review profiles and permission sets.
Create a few new scratch orgs and obtain the same result

Comment: Hi. Are you aware of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com where you will find a lot more focus on Salesforce-related issues?

Comment: If you're a partner, have a look at [this thread on the partner forums](https://partners.salesforce.com/0D54V00007JaZnS). To summarise, it might relate to Hyperforce, but the Salesforce ISV Platform Expert has not confirmed.

Comment: This also happens if you try to add your scratch org to VS Code using SFDX and if you try to get a token using username/password for a Connected App.